# K&R Exercise 1.16 - Limitation on line length

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie, c89

I'm learning C from K&R's "[The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)" book. I'm doing the exercises specified in the book. I'm on exercise number 1.16, but I don't understand it.

Exercise 1.16:

> Revise the main routine of the longest-line program so it will
>   correctly print the length of arbitrarily long input lines, and as
>   much as possible of the text.

My questions:

1. "...as much as possible of the text..." - is there some limitation on string length? Maybe in standard headers there's a variable with the max allowed value of string length?
2. "...the length of arbitrarily long input lines..." - but in the code MAXLINE is defined as 1000. It is limited size too. I see some solutions [here](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K&R2_solutions%3aChapter_1%3aExercise_16), but in my opinion it is not solution decision, since on the former there is a restriction on length of a line (1000 characters).

Maybe I don't understood the task. My understanding is I must remove the 1000-character limitation.

Comment: I don't have my K&R with me now, so I can't really check the requirements of the longest-line program. Remember, though, you can read, print and count single characters with no need to save them in a string.

Comment: @pmg But according task's text, I must and print max line text too.

Comment: Well ... if you must print the longest line, you gotta save it somewhere. My suggestion is no good for the exercise, sorry.

Comment: You don't have to save all of it at once, though.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's a pretty early exercise in K&R, you're just supposed to do some  minor changes to the code, not a total redesign of the code.

1. > "...as much as possible of the text..."

   is up to you to interpret. I'd do it by printing what's stored in the `longest` buffer. i.e. print out up to 1000 characters of the line. Again, it's an early exercise, with little introduction to dynamically allocated memory yet. And at the time K&R was written, storing away arbitrarily long text lines wasn't as feasible as it is today.
2. > "...the length of arbitrarily long input lines..."

   Is a hard requirement. You're supposed to find the correct length no matter how long it is (at least within the bounds of an `int`. )

One way to solve this problem is:

- After the call to getline(), check if the last character read into the `line` buffer is a newline ('\n')
- If it is, you read a complete line. The `len` variable is the correct length of the line(the return value of getline(), and no special consideration is needed compared to to original code.
- If it is *not* , you did not read the entire line, and need to hunt for the end of this line. You add a while loop, calling getchar() until it returns a newline (or EOF), and count the number of characters you read in that loop. Just do `len++` to count.
- When the while loop is done, the new `len` is now the actual length of the line, but our buffer just has the first 999 characters of it.
- As before, you store away (the copy() function call) the current `line` buffer (max 1000 chars) if this line is the longest so far.
- When you're done, you print out the stored line as before (the `longest` buffer) and the `max` variable for the length.

  - Due to the above mentioned while loop that `max` length is now correct.
  - If the `longest` line indeed was longer than 1000 chars. you at least print out those first 999 chars - which is "as much as possible".

I'll not spoil it and post the code you need to accomplish this, but it is just 6 lines of code that you need to add to the longest-line program of exercise 1-16.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to translate it to Russian, and to write code tomorrow. Now is night, and I want to sleep. Thank's to all!

Answer (score 2):

1. On modern machines "as much as possible of the text" is likely to be all of the text, thanks to automatically line-wrapping terminal programs.  That book was written when teletype terminals were still in use.  There is no limitation on string length other than perhaps memory limitations of the machine you're working on.
2. They're expecting you to add some kind of loop to read characters and look for newlines rather than assuming that a read into the `MAXLINE` sized buffer is going to contain a newline for sure.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that `4096` char limit per line in text file on Linux. It's supported beyond that now? since when?

Comment: `automatically line-wrapping terminal programs` - what is it?

Comment: @DoSparKot, try it - I'm sure you'll see there is no such limit.  I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: @Bush - a terminal program that wraps text to the next line when it reaches the right side of the window.  Like line-wrapping in a word processor.

Comment: ah.. it was `fgets()` and the `LINE_MAX` limit.

Answer (score 0):

here is my version:

```
int getline(char s[],int lim)
{
    int c,i;
    for(i=0;i<lim-1&&(c=getchar())!=EOF&&c!='\n';++i)
        s[i]=c;
    if(c=='\n')
    {
        s[i]=c;
        ++i;
    }
    if(c!=EOF)
    {
        while((c=getchar())!=EOF&&c!='\n')
            i++;
    }
    s[i]='\0';
    return i;
}
    #define MAXLINE 1000
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max=0;
    while((len=getline(line,MAXLINE))>1)
    {
        if(len>max)
        {
            max=len;
            copy(longest,line);
        }
    }
    if(max>0)
    {
        printf("%d:%s",max,longest);
    }
    return 0;
```

for some unknown reasons ,the example code doesn't work in my pc
particularly，when the condition is 'len>0',the loop won't end
i think the main reason is that when you type nothing,but you still have to press enter,so it is received as '\n',and the len is 1;
i think it satisfy the requirement that print the  length of arbitrarily long input lines, and as much as possible of the text.
[And it works like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfIEx.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include

    main()
    {
       long tlength = 0;
       short input, llength = 1;
       while (llength > 0)  {
          llength = 0;
          while ((input = getchar()) != EOF) {
              ++llength;
              if (input == '\n')
              break;
          }
          tlength = tlength + llength;
          printf("\nLength of just above line : %5d\n\n", llength);
       }
       printf("\n\tLength of entire text : %8ld\n", tlength);
       return 0;
    }
```

According to me, This question only wants the length of each arbitrarily line + At last the length of entire text.

Try to run this code and tell me is it correct according to question because i too confuse in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I want to offer that this exercise actually makes more sense if imagine that the limit of the number of characters you can copy is very small -- say, 100 characters -- and that your program is supposed to judge between lines that are longer than that limit.

(If you actually change the limit so that it's very small, the code becomes easier to test: if it picks out the first line that hits that small limit, you'll know your code isn't working, whereas if it returns the first however-many characters of the longest line, it's working.)

Keep the part of the code that copies and counts characters until it hits a newline or EOF or the line-size-limit. Add code that picks up where this counting and copying leaves off, and which will keep counting even after the copying has stopped, so long as getchar() still hasn't returned an EOF or a newline.

Answer (score 0):

My solution: just below the call to getLine

```
if ( line[len-1] != '\n' && line[len-1] != EOF) //if end of line or file wasnt found after max length
{
    int c;
    while ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && c != EOF ) 
        len++; //keep counting length until end of line or file is found
}
```

to test it, change MAXLINE to 25